# Why the shape of dish antenna is in parabolic shape?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, antennas

All dish antenna are in the shape of parabola. Is the curve of parabola anyhow related to physical quantity of the wave of transmission? Are there different curved antennas for different waves?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort

Answer (score 2):

When signals strike any place on a parabolic dish, they are re-directed to the focus of the parabola, where the antenna is positioned